# Include external folders in project file browser

Tags: textmate2

In Textmate 1 I was used to being able to include folders from different locations in my project drawer. Is this still possible in Textmate 2?

Example: I’ve got the follwing (real) file structure:

```
/my_software
    /system_a
        /module_b
            /src_b (This is my actual project folder)
/other_software
    /system_y
        /module_z
            /src_z (I want to have this folder in my project file tree, for reference)
```

And I want my Textmate 2 project file browser look like this, which was easy in Textmate 1 by adding existing folders to the drawer:

```
/src_b
/src_z
```

Is this still possible in Textmate 2? E.g. by adding the external folder in the .tm_properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this currently is to just use [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link). Here is how you do this from the command line considering the above directory structure:

```
$ mkdir my_project
$ cd my_project
$ ln -s /my_software/system_a/module_b/src_b .
$ ln -s /other_software/system_y/module_z/src_z .
$ mate .
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That’s what I ended up doing. However not very comfortable, since I have to exclude these symlinks for version control.